# Upgrade Pgbouncer

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, upgrade, pgbouncer

I need some advice for upgrading pgbouncer. I couldn't find any document which tells me how to upgrade pgbouncer. I tried the command

```bash
apt install pgbouncer
```

I wonder if there is another good, efficient way of upgrading or not. What should your advice be to me for upgrading process?

Answer (score 0):

We have done pgbouncer upgrade on centos using `yum upgrade pgbouncer`, with it either new package will create `rpmnew` files or the existing one will be renamed to `rpmold`, in either case no files will be removed, depending on it you may need to rename some files. I think same can be done using `apt-install`. For a zero-downtime approach you need to have multiple instances running on same machine listening to same port using `so_reuseport` then you could perform a rolling upgrade. More details here https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/running-multiple-pgbouncer-instances-with-systemd/